# ProgressView Not Updating

Tags: swift, swiftui, firebase-storage

I am trying to observe the progress when uploading an image to firebase storage. The progress is being updated in the console however my ProgressView does not update. Everything else seems to be working as expected. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
class UserManager: ObservableObject  {

@Published var taskProgress: Float = 0.0
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser



func uploadProfilePicture(image: UIImage) {
    
    let uploadRef = FirebaseReferenceManager.storage.reference(withPath: "profile/\(user!.uid)")
    
    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else {
        return
    }
    
    let uploadMetaData = StorageMetadata.init()
    uploadMetaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    
    let taskReference = uploadRef.putData(imageData, metadata: uploadMetaData) { (downloadMetaData, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            print("Successfully Uploaded Profile Picture to Firebase Storage")
            let downloadRef = FirebaseReferenceManager.storage.reference(withPath: "profile/\(self.user!.uid)")
            downloadRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                FirebaseReferenceManager.root.collection(FirebaseKeys.CollectionPath.users).document(self.user!.uid).setData([FirebaseKeys.UsersFieldPath.photoURL : url!.absoluteString], merge: true)
            }
            
            

        }
    }

    
    taskReference.observe(.progress) { [weak self] (snapshot) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let pctThere = snapshot.progress?.fractionCompleted else {return}
            print(pctThere)
            self?.taskProgress = Float(pctThere)
        }

    }
    taskReference.resume()
    

}
```

}

In my view I put the following

```
@EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager

ProgressView(value: userManager.taskProgress).progressViewStyle(LinearProgressViewStyle())
```

Here is how the class is initialized:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
@StateObject var userManager = UserManager()

var body: some View {
    
    TabView {
        
        HomeView().tabItem {
            Image("home")
            Text("Home")
            
        }
        

        SearchView().tabItem {
            Image("search")
            Text("Search")
            
        }
        
        DiscoverView().tabItem {
            Image("discover")
            Text("Discover")
            
        }
        
        OrdersView().tabItem {
            Image("calendar")
            Text("Orders")
            
        }
        
        InboxView().tabItem {
            Image("inbox")
            Text("Inbox")
            
        }
    }
    .environmentObject(userManager)
}
```

}

And then I pass it down deeper into the hierarchy using

```
    @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager
```

Here is where uploadProfilePicture() is called:

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary

@Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode


func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
    
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
    
    return imagePicker
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}


func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

}


class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
 
    let parent: ImagePicker
    @ObservedObject private var userManager = UserManager()

 
    init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
 
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
 
        if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            parent.selectedImage = image
            userManager.uploadProfilePicture(image: image)
        }
        

        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using `@State var userManager`?

Comment: Have you checked if `self` is nil?

Comment: Try using @ObservedObject over the @EnvironmentObject on your `userManager` then set an instance. Eg. `@ObservedObject var userManager = UserManager()` then reference it as a ViewModel. If you need it as an @Environment, consider changing it to a singleton.

Comment: @Todd I just tried it and it doesn't work but thanks.

Comment: @George_E yes. Maybe I wasn't clear but the Im able to print the progress. Eg. onAppear { print(userManager.taskProgress) } it's just the progressview that isn't updating.

Comment: @devOP1 Using `onAppear` it will only print once. But I mean where you have `self?.taskProgress = Float(pctThere)` - where you actually update the `@Published` value. If `self` is nil (possibly deallocated) then `taskProgress` will not be set multiple times, therefore your progress view won't update again. You could print `self` and if it is `nil` then there is the problem. You could also debug this by adding `didSet { print("taskProgress changed to:", taskProgress) }` to your `@Published` `taskProgress` value to check if the value is recognized to be changing.

Comment: @George_E I tried the `didSet` and the `@Published taskProgress` value is indeed changing

Comment: @devOP1 Okay. Can you show the code of how you inject the environment object into the view, like where the class is initialised and what you pass into `.environmentObject(...)`?

Comment: @George_E I just added it

Comment: @devOP1 This is really weird, I can't seem to reproduce the issue. Rather than using `ProgressView` try use `Text("\(userManager.taskProgress)")` to see if this is an issue with `ProgressView` itself or just view body updates. I'm also assuming that `ProgressView` code is already in the view `body`, and not just set to a variable (it's a bit unclear). If that doesn't update, I'm not sure...

Comment: @George_E That doesn't seem to work either. Thanks anyways

Comment: Since you aren't showing where you make the call to `uploadProfilePicture`, is it possible that you've unintentionally created a *different* instance of `UserManager` somewhere that you're using? If you search for `UserManager()`, does more than one occurrence show up?

Comment: @jnpdx you may be on to something here... I have added the code snippet where I call upload profile picture however how do I make it conform to the original UserManager instance? I tried `@EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager` and that doesnt work.

Comment: Added an answer -- this is assuming that `ImagePicker` exists in an environment where `@EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager` is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, we deduced that it was a different `UserManager` instance. Here would be an example of how to pass the *same* instance into the `Coordinator` (this is assuming that ImagePicker exists in an environment where `@EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager` is available).

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject private var userManager: UserManager //<-- Here
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, userManager: userManager)  //<-- Here
    }
    
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        let parent: ImagePicker
        let userManager: UserManager
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker, userManager: UserManager) {  //<-- Here
            self.parent = parent
            self.userManager = userManager  //<-- Here
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = image
                userManager.uploadProfilePicture(image: image)
            }
            
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```